# Javascript Multiply Function Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to javascript and am trying to get the calculation below to perform as the user inputs the values. I am unable to get the calculation to run at all and am not sure where I am going wrong. I would appreciate any assitance in solving the problem and understanding what is incorrect.

The inputs are:

```
<input name="ConceptEstimate_GrandTotal" type="text" />
<input name="ConceptEstimate_Exp" type="text" />
<input name="ConceptEstimate_Cap" type="text" />
<input name="ConceptEstimate_ProjMgmt" type="text" />
<input name="ConceptEstimate_PA" type="text" />
<input name="ConceptEstimate_DB" type="text" />
<input name="ConceptEstimate_Test" type="text" />
<input name="ConceptEstimate_Deploy" type="text" />
<input name="Capital_PA" type="text" disabled="disabled" />
<input name="Expense_PA" type="text" disabled="disabled" />
<input name="Capital_DB" type="text" disabled="disabled" />
<input name="Expense_DB" type="text" disabled="disabled" />
<input name="Capital_TD" type="text" disabled="disabled" />
<input name="Expense_TD" type="text" disabled="disabled" />
<input name="Capital_S" type="text" disabled="disabled" />
<input name="Expense_S" type="text" disabled="disabled" />
<input name="Capital_Total" type="text" disabled="disabled" />
<input name="Expense_Total" type="text" disabled="disabled" />
```

And the function is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".input").keyup(function () {
    var a = +$("#ConceptEstimate_GrandTotal")[0].value;
    var b = +$("#ConceptEstimate_Exp")[0].value;
    var c = +$("#ConceptEstimate_Cap")[0].value;
    var d = +$("#ConceptEstimate_ProjMgmt")[0].value;
    var e = +$("#ConceptEstimate_PA")[0].value;
    var f = +$("#ConceptEstimate_DB")[0].value;
    var g = +$("#ConceptEstimate_Test")[0].value;
    var h = +$("#ConceptEstimate_Deploy")[0].value;

    $("#Capital_PA")[0].value = a * (c/100) * (e/100);
    $("#Expense_PA")[0].value = a * (b/100) * (e/100);
    $("#Capital_DB")[0].value = a * (c/100) * (f/100);
    $("#Expense_DB")[0].value = a * (b/100) * (f/100);
    $("#Capital_TD")[0].value = (a * (c/100) * (g/100)) + (a * (c/100) * (h/100));
    $("#Expense_TD")[0].value = (a * (b/100) * (g/100)) + (a * (b/100) * (h/100));
    $("#Capital_S")[0].value = a * (c/100) * (d/100);
    $("#Expense_S")[0].value = a * (b/100) * (d/100);

  });
});
```

Comment: Your selectors are all wrong. Or your html is all wrong. You don't have any ID's in the html you have provided, or classes for that matter, both of which are required for the javascript to work the way it is currently written. `$(".input")` matches 0 elements in the html you have provided.

Comment: You are correct and again I am new trying to learn. I changed the <input name= to <input id=. I also changed the $(".input") to $("input"), which have corrected the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot wrong here.

1) You're mixing up jQuery and non-jQuery too much. Don't use `$(selector)[0].value` when `$(selector).val()` is more appropriate.

2) You're trying to target your elements by their ID when they only have a name. `$("#Capital_PA")` should be `$('[name="Capital_PA"]')`, for example.

3) Your `.input` selector is targeting a class when it should be targeting the `input` element itself. Like: `$('input')`.

[Here's some corrected code](http://jsfiddle.net/andyuws/H683T/)

Comment: OP, I've added a `jQuery` tag. I assume that you do actually _want_ to use it and haven't just added it to your code by mistake...

Comment: Thanks Andy, this was a big help.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to find elements like this

```
$("#ConceptEstimate_GrandTotal")
```

This means "use jQuery to find an element which has the *id* of `ConceptEstimate_GrandTotal`"

When we look at your *HTML* the only similar element is

```
<input name="ConceptEstimate_GrandTotal" type="text" />
```

**However** this element has a *name* of `ConceptEstimate_GrandTotal`, not an *id*.

Therefore, the result of your `$(...)` will be just an empty *jQuery* object (let's call it `x`),
 so **`x[0]` is *undefined*** and you can't do `undefined.value`, so you'll get an error and everything stops.

This applies to everywhere you try to get an element.

The problem might have been clearer if you kept to *vanilla JavaScript* `document.getElementById(id_attribute_value)`, as this will give `null` (falsy) and not an empty object (truthy) when it doesn't find anything

---

Easiest way to fix it is add the relevant *id* attributes to your elements

```
<input name="ConceptEstimate_GrandTotal"
       id="ConceptEstimate_GrandTotal"
       type="text"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need some basics :

```
<input />                  -> $('input')
<input id="whatever" />    -> $('#whatever')
<input class="whatever" /> -> $('.whatever')
<input name="whatever" />  -> $('[name="whatever"]')
```

Answer (score -1):

I think it might be because the values you get from your form are all Strings. 
did you try to parseInt() the values?

For example

```
$("#Capital_PA")[0].value = parseInt(a) * (parseInt(c)/100) * (parseInt(e)/100)
```

Can you provide some output or error messages if this is not the case?

In addition you have to add the attribute id to your input fields.

Next Question I have is: why isn't there a "value" attribute provided?
How do you set the values of your input fields?

Comment: by focusing the input and typing into it. Hence the keyup event.

Comment: Is the keyup event even called? Maybe you should try to change the keyup function to: $('form input:text').keyup(function()... because you don't have any class defined named .input.

Comment: The values are already coerced to integers. Weirdly, that was pretty much the only thing the OP got right.

Comment: @Andy Weird indeed o.O